# Stamp Errors in layout

Tags: analog, simulation, layout

I am working on layout. I have two power supplies. For this when I took a via from Metal1 to n well I got no issues. But when i consider another via from Metal1 to n well, I am getting the following issues: a. welnotr_StampErrorMult, b. welnotr_StampErrorConnect. Please any one can suggest why these errors are coming and how to modify the layout?[image]

Comment: No indication which tool you are using, or which process? Good luck finding anyone who can guess!

Comment: I am using Cadence virtuoso tool. Process node is 180nm.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that the two vias are only connected by the nwell. Try to connect the two vias on ME1. But I guess this problem is already outdated, as the post is already a year old :D